# How to prove that a dihedral group is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I have this exercise:

> Let $f$ be a function such that $$f(x,y)=(-x,y)$$ and $h$ the rotation of the plane respect to the origin in an angle of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Let $G$ be such that $$G=\lbrace f^ih^j\mid i=0,1;j=0,1,2,...,(n-1)\rbrace$$ and the usual product of functions $*$. If $G$ is a dihedral group prove that:
>
> a) If $n$ is odd and $a\in G$ such that $a*b=b*a$ for all $b\in G$, then $a=e$ ($e$ its the identity of the group).
>
> b) If $n$ is even, prove that exists $a\in G$, $a\neq e$, such that $a*b=b*a$, for all $b\in G$.
>
> c) If $n$ is even, find every element $a\in G$ such that $a*b=b*a$, for all $b\in G$.

I don't know how to do it.
Help please.

Comment: Find the smallest $n$ for which you *can* do it.

Comment: The current title and the question do not match. Each of (a), (b), and (c) concern commutativity, yes, but none of them ask you to demonstrate that $G$ is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $G$ is a dihedral group, it satisfies the relations
$$f^2=h^n=1,hf=fh^{-1}.$$
For how to get these relations, you may refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741004/how-to-verify-fh-h-1f-for-dihedral-group-of-order-2n?rq=1).

Let $z\in G$ such that $zg=gz$ for all $g\in G$.
Then in particular you have
$$zh=hz \text{ and } zf=fz.$$
Write $z=f^ih^j$.
By solving the first equation, you will get $i=0$.
And by solving the second equation, you will get $j=0$ when $n$ is odd, and $j=0,n/2$ when $n$ is even.
Hence if $n$ is odd, $z$ must be $e$, and if $n$ is even, $z$ is $e$ or $h^{n/2}$.

Comment: I don't know how to get the equations, sorry but the algebra it's so difficult for me.